# Does OAuth-2.0 supports ipv6?

Tags: xcode, oauth-2.0, ipv6

I was implementing yelp v3 for an iOS app but I am unsure about this problem.Will the app get rejected if I use OAuth or should I use NSURLSession.
Thank you !

Comment: Did you perform the required test on an IPv6-only network?

Comment: Yes ,It didn't authenticate